# Different result for two similar image convolutional neural network

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, dataset, classification, conv-neural-network

I've trained simple convolutional neural network for image classification. it reached 97% accuracy for validation set. my dataset includes images taken by camera from paper book and also screenshot from pdf. but when i want to predict image taken from book by webcam, the model accuracy and confidence is very bad.
these are images:
[image: image taken by mobile]

image taken by mobile, high predict accuracy

[image: image taken by webcam]

very bad result.

for better generalization, I also added random noise to my dataset images but it's not good yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even i face this kind of problem in my computer vision tasks.
i think there is some image quality difference b/w your webcam image and mobile phone image...
what i do is mix both types (can also include images taken from other cameras just to increase the variety) of images in your training data and validation data.
This would generalize your model on any data

Comment: Thanks for your advice Prajot, It's hard to find low quality camera and take picture, what do you think about color augmentation or resize some of my training images to smaller size and resize back to original size to reduce quality?

Comment: resize wont help but color augmentation might help  i guess, Or try to include atleast webcam images in your training data.